# How to pass a generic type through a non-generic class function

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that copies generic data from an API to a generic array (`apiData.copyTo()`). I solved that by doing the following:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    T[] data;

    public void SetData(Action<T[]> action) {
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}

// ushort as example:
Foo<ushort> someFoo;
someFoo.SetData(buffer => apiData.copyTo(buffer));
```

However, after some changes in the data layout I'd like to create a private class for the generic data and make the Foo class non-generic this results in the following problem I'm facing:

```
public class Foo {

    private class Bar<T> {
        T[] data;

        public void SetData(Action<T[]> action) {
            action.Invoke(data);
        }
    }

    private Bar<ushort> bar; // Example generic, could be everything

    // The problem lies here:
    // T is not known to Foo, how to fix this?
    public void SetData(Action<T[]> action) {
        bar.SetData(action);

        // Some other stuff...
    }       
}
```

As you can see the problem is that the generic type `T` is not known to the `Foo` class. How can I still pass the `Action` to the private class `Bar<T>` within `Foo`?

Please note that this is a minimal example to make my problem clear.

Comment: You seem to be conflicting. Why you want to hide T (by introducing Bar<T>) from caller? And at the same time you want to pass T (means caller decide what is T)? What is your real problem?

Comment: If you make `bar` a `Bar<ushort>`, you have to make `Foo.SetData(Action<ushort[]> action)`.  Why not just make `Foo` generic?

Comment: @JayBuckman That's what OP wants to move away from - for whatever reason.

Comment: Bar<T> is either a ushort or byte at the moment. Bar<T> will also contain an IntPtr of this data-array which I need to pass the data to the GPU. However, the data type can change depending on external modifications, which means I need to be able to re-set the data (using SetData()) with the provided API-function `copyTo()` which was mentioned. The problem is that the type is not known beforehand and I need to be able to construct an empty Foo as it also holds other information. I'm working with 'raw' data, and am deriving the types from it. The variable `bar` is created with the `Activator`.

Comment: Actually, I do not think Generics is the way to go at all here. I'll try to come up with an answer, later.

Comment: Thanks. The API function signature is as follows: `void copyTo<T>(T[] array)`.

Comment: @Patrick2607 Would something like this fit your requirements: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uhNfyl ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're asking:

```
public class Foo
{
    public interface IBar
    {
        void SetData<T>(Action<T[]> action);
        Type GetBarType();
    }
    private class Bar<T>: IBar
    {
        //I changed this to a list since an empty array probably won't do you much good.
        List<T> data = new List<T>();

        public Type GetBarType()
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }

        public void SetData<TAction>(Action<TAction[]> action)
        {
            if(typeof(T) == typeof(TAction))
                action.Invoke(data as TAction[]);
        }
    }

    private IBar bar; 

    public void SetData<T>(Action<T[]> action)
    {
        if(bar?.GetBarType() == typeof(T))
            bar.SetData(action);
        else
        {
            bar = new Bar<T>();
            bar.SetData(action);
        }
        // Some other stuff...
    }
}

public class DoStuff
{
    public DoStuff()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.SetData<int>((data) => {  /*do somthing wth this container*/ });
        foo.SetData<byte>((data) => {  /*do somthing wth this container*/ });
        foo.SetData<ushort>((data) => {  /*do somthing wth this container*/ });
        foo.SetData<ulong>((data) => {  /*do somthing wth this container*/ });
        foo.SetData<string>((data) => {  /*do somthing wth this container*/ });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't work with `int` in `foo.SetData<int>` as the type is not known beforehand, that's the whole problem. Also, I use a pre-allocated 1D-array because the data needs to be sent to the GPU in another part of the application.

Comment: int was just an example, you can use any type. and change back to an array, you just have to initialize it. Maybe we aren't understanding what you mean by "beforehand". At some point the the type has to be known, we are just attempting to delay the initialization of Bar until the type is known.